# Heroku addon for web analytics

Tags: heroku, google-analytics, web-analytics

Are there any addons for web analytics for heroku? I already used analytics from google but as I want to track the analytics of an open source project (MEAN.js) which should be transferable to another user I would prefer to have all in one place (heroku). Do they provide free plans for open source projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try [Keen IO](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/keen), they have a free tier you could use to test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. The free "Developer" plan is limited to 50000 events. But this should satisfy my requirements (the next "Startup" plan limited to 100000 events is about 20$/month). I have a look if all the metrics I am interested in are included...